# How to use a tail-recursion with guards for splitting a list into two ones?

Tags: haskell, tuples, list-comprehension

If I have a list lets say `[1,2,3,4]`, how can I create a tuple of two lists so that the first list contains the odd elements and the second one - the even elements. How can I do this with a tail-recursion?

*For example:*

```
    Input  : [1,2,3,4]
    Output : ([1,3],[2,4]) with tail recursion and not ranges. [|x<-...]
```

So far I have tried something like:

```
sumt::[Int]->([Int],[Int])
sumt []=([],[])
sumt (x:xs)
    | x `mod` 2==0 = x: (fst $ tupl xs)
    | otherwise    = x: (snd $ tupl xs) where 
    tupl []=([],[])
    tupl (y:ys)=y:(tupl ys)   //how can I put the condition here ? I need it 
                            //to be aware of both guard cases at each iteration
```

I basically need two local lists that are formed by each guard case and at the end they are placed in a tuple.

Comment: Are you sure you want this to be tail-recursive? Why? Also, the code you've tried is not tail-recursive.

Comment: `// Comment` isn't a Haskell comment. Use `-- Comment`.

Comment: I am trying to  solve the problem using guards and tail-recursion.Is there any way  i can generate the empty tuple and the empty lists and populate them using recursion

Comment: `even` and `odd` are functions in the Prelude. `even 4` will return `True`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do it with explicit recursion is to use a tail-recursive helper function with two accumulators for the result lists:

```
sumt :: [Int] -> ([Int], [Int])
sumt = go [] []
  where

    -- Each recursive call is directly to ‘go’,
    -- so it’s tail-recursive.
    go os es (x:xs)
      | x `mod` 2 == 0 = go os (x:es) xs
      | otherwise = go (x:os) es xs

    -- In the base case, it returns a tuple with
    -- the accumulated results in the proper order.
    go os es [] = (reverse os, reverse es)
```

A much simpler way to do this is with the `partition` function from `Data.List`:

```
sumt :: (Integral a) => [a] -> ([a], [a])
sumt = partition odd
```

If you look at the definition of `partition`, it’s not implemented with explicit recursion, but with `foldr`. Here it is with `odd` inlined:

```
sumt = foldr select ([], [])
  where
    select x ~(os, es)
      | odd x = (x:os, es)
      | otherwise = (os, x:es)
```

This has the advantage of being *streaming*: it doesn’t include the O(n) step of reversing the accumulated lists at the end, it just builds the results incrementally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir !

Answer (score 3):

Tail recursive functions are ones in which the final result of a function is a call back to the same function.  In Haskell, this means that the right-hand side of an equation must be a call to the function.  So, for example,
   f (x:xs) n = f xs (n+1)
is tail recursive, while
   f' (x:xs) = 1 + f' xs
is not - because while there is a recursive call, it is not the result of the function.  Instead, the evaluation of (+) is the result.

In the case of your code, this means you need something like this:

```
sumt_tr :: [Int] -> ([Int],[Int])
sumt_tr xs = go xs ([],[])
    where
    go [] (os,es) = (reverse os,reverse es)
    go (x:xs) (os,es) | x `mod` 2 == 0 = go xs (os,x:es)
                      | otherwise      = go xs (x:os,es)
```

Here, the function `go` (local to sumt_tr) is tail recursive, because each equation for `go` directly calls `go` again.  Notice that, in order to write `go` as tail recursive, I needed to accumulate the result by passing it as a second argument, to be returned when the end of the list is reached.

Comment: Ok so in order to do this i must provide the initial value of the tuple  ([],[]).I thought that i could somehow first create the lists and them pack them up at the end in a tuple.Something like -> Iterate over initial list , take 1 element at a time insert in one of the two local list variables and then put them in a tuple.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian yes you need the initial value of the accumulator.  As you proceed through each tail recursive call, you accumulate by adding a new value to the accumulator.  In cases like this, where the initial value is what is called the 'unit' value (i.e., it acts as the identity for a particular operation) and where that operation is monoidal (binary and associative), you can replace the initial value with `mempty`.  So the call to `go xs ([],[])` in the code above can be replace by `go xs mempty`.  It's really worth reading about and undertanding monoids in Haskell, btw.

Comment: Could you refer a source for further reading?Until now i was dabbling in Haskell using my intuition but i know there is concrete set-theory math in how the things work,and for greater understanding.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian there are a lot of good online resources.  [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com) (Learn You A Haskell) is a great resource.  There is also [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), which has the benefit of embedded comments from readers, but is a little old now and some of the code in later chapters is a little out of date (in which case, reading the comments help because suggestions for updated code are posted).  If you want to spend money, then [Programming Haskell from First Principles](http://haskellbook.com) is my absolute favourite.